# Parsing svg using .NET XLinq - 'xlink' is an undeclared prefix

Tags: .net, xml, svg, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to parse a string of svg into an XElement using the following line:

```
XElement productSvg = XElement.Parse(svgString);
```

But I'm getting the following exception: ***XmlException - 'xlink' is an undeclared prefix***
Here's my svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg id="svg62433" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 595.19 596.32" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
        <g id="g7123">
            <path id="path5588" d="m404.54,164.29c0,121.64-98.612,220.26-220.26,220.26-121.64,0-220.26-98.612-220.26-220.26,0-121.64,98.612-220.26,220.26-220.26,121.64,0,220.26,98.612,220.26,220.26z" transform="matrix(0.01922722,0.99981514,-0.99981514,0.01922722,536.42634,464.95177)" fill="none"/>
            <text id="text5590" style="writing-mode:lr-tb;letter-spacing:0px;text-anchor:middle;word-spacing:0px;text-align:center;" font-weight="bold" font-size="64px" line-height="125%" font-stretch="normal" font-variant="normal" font-style="normal" font-family="'Swis721 Cn BT'">
                <textPath id="textPath5598" xlink:href="#path5588" startOffset="50%">
                    <tspan id="contentTopText" style="writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:middle;text-align:center;" font-weight="bold" font-size="64px" line-height="125%" font-stretch="normal" font-variant="normal" font-style="normal" font-family="'Swis721 Cn BT'">Text Here</tspan>
                </textPath>
            </text>
        </g>
</svg>
```

Does anyone know how to successfully parse xml attributes in .NET XLinq that contain namespaces?

Comment: Well whether it is LINQ to XML or any other XML API, if you want to use it you need namespace well-formed XML to start with and that means the `xlink` prefix needs to be declared with e.g. `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`, like any other namespace prefix used. If you don't have that you need a HTML5 parser instead which .NET so far (4.0) does not have.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, the xlink namespace is declared in the parent svg tag

Comment: @svick, cool, for those who experience this issue I found a great answer here: http://aspnetgotyou.blogspot.com/2010/06/xdocument-or-xelement-with-xmlnamespace.html

Comment: I don't see how you could get the error message of an undeclared prefix if the prefix is declared. So it sounds as if the XML you posted is different from the one you get the error with.

Comment: nope, I was definitely getting the exception, wouldn't have bothered with posting the question otherwise. The link I found below was a great solution. Mind you, I'm not parsing an actual svg xml document here, it's a string of svg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a great solution to this problem, worked perfect for me:

http://aspnetgotyou.blogspot.com/2010/06/xdocument-or-xelement-with-xmlnamespace.html